# jQuery datepicker change with maxDate range

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I am creating one control for date range. which have below requirements.

- **Form** and **To** should be till yesterday no future dates [**able to achive**]
- Restrict maximum 3 months of different.

  ```
  $("#from-datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
      maxDate: "-1d",
      onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        console.log(selectedDate);
          $("#to-datepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        //$("#to-datepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
      }
  });
  $("#to-datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
      maxDate: "-1d",
      onClose: function (selectedDate) {
          $("#from-datepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
      }
  });
  ```

Here is [JSfiddle](http://jsbin.com/datedatepick/2/edit)

Comment: You are in the good way: set the `maxDate` of the `to-datepicker` (selectedDate + 3 Months) when closing the from-datepicker, and the same (minDate) when closing the to-datepicker.
Beware of not exceeding the yesterday limit also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the result:

```
$(function() {
    $("#from-datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        maxDate: "-1d",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {             
            // Set 'TO' minDate
            $("#to-datepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);             

            // Set 'TO' maxDate at 3 months if before yesterday
            var dt = new Date($(this).datepicker("getDate"));
            dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + 3);
            if(dt < Date.now()) {
                $("#to-datepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
            }
        }
    });
    $("#to-datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        maxDate: "-1d",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            // Set 'FROM' maxDate
            $("#from-datepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);

            // Set 'FROM' minDate at 3 months if before yesterday
            var dt = new Date($(this).datepicker("getDate"));
            dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 3);
            if(dt < Date.now()) {
                $("#from-datepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/382z6ev5/
(Sorry, I got a problem with your jsbin)

Comment: Great. But I cannot see the difference in the fiddle, what did you change?